# new NumberInt() not giving expected result in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In my `movies` collection, I have a `year` field, which is a String (example: `"year": "2010"`)

I want to update year in all my collection, changing it to an int so I can compare it to other int fields.

I tried the following:

```
db.movies.updateMany({}, {$set: {year: new NumberInt("$year")}})
```

which changes every year value to `0` (int), and not the string value converted to int.

I also tried `db.movies.updateMany({}, {$set: {year: parseInt("$year", 10)}})`, but it returns `NaN` everywhere.

I have been trying for a while now and I can't see what I'm doing wrong! Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: In robomongo UI, it spells "$year", so I guess not! It throws me an error when I try without quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can try classic way

```
var customUpdate = function(document) {
  var val = parseInt(document.year, 10);
  db.movies.update(
    {_id:document._id}, 
    {$set: {year: val}}
  );
}

db.movies.find().forEach(customUpdate)
```

[Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)